# Неправильный вывод текстовых строк, полученных из файла

Tags: c, файлы

Помогите разобраться. Программа создает одномерный массив, заполненный случайными числами. Далее она запрашивает у пользователя ввести число, которое нужно добавить в начало массива, и добавляет его в массив. Исходный и результирующий массивы записываются в файл. Проблема возникает, когда я хочу считать построчно текст файла и вывести его в консоль. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 36;

int main(void)
{
    int* arrayPointer;
    int i, N;
    int value;
    FILE* f;
    char buff[255];
    int index, element;
    puts("Enter the size of array(non-negative integer):");
    scanf_s("%d", &N);

    if ((arrayPointer = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int))) == 0)
    {
        puts("Memory allocation error!!!");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (fopen_s(&f, "rez.txt", "w+") != 0)
    {
        perror("Error with opening a file");
        exit(1);
    }

    fputs("Input array:\n", f);

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        arrayPointer[i] = rand() % N;
        fprintf(f, "%d element : %d\n", i, arrayPointer[i]);
    }

    puts("Enter the integer value of element to add to the beggining of array:");
    scanf_s("%d", &value);

    if ((arrayPointer = (int*)realloc(arrayPointer,
                                      (N + 1) * sizeof(int))) == 0)
    {
        puts("Memory allocation error");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = N; i > 0; i--)
    {
        arrayPointer[i] = arrayPointer[i - 1];
    }

    fprintf(f, "Adding %d to the array...\n", value);
    arrayPointer[0] = value;
    fputs("Result Array:\n", f);

    for (i = 0; i < N + 1; i++)
    {
        fprintf(f, "%d element : %d\n", i, arrayPointer[i]);
    }

    while (fgets(buff, 255, f) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", buff);
    }

    free(arrayPointer);
    fclose(f);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А становиться для чтения на начало массива?

```
fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET); // <- вот это добавьте

while (fgets(buff, 255, f) != NULL) {
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Только начал изучать Си, забыл немного. А подскажите еще, откуда вообще берутся эти белые строки в консоли?

Comment: Не подскажу... может, какие настройки среды? в общем, не знаю, а врать не хочу.

Comment: Спасибо большое, наконец-то разобрался